# Acquire WriteLock before writing shared resource

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I am a beginner in multi-threading and came across this example on `ReadWriteLock`.

**ScoreBoard**

```
public class ScoreBoard {
private boolean scoreUpdated = false;
private int score = 0;
    String health = "Not Available";
final ReentrantReadWriteLock rrwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
public String getMatchHealth() {
    rrwl.readLock().lock();
    if (scoreUpdated) {
        rrwl.readLock().unlock();
        rrwl.writeLock().lock();
        try {
          if (scoreUpdated) {
              score = fetchScore();
              scoreUpdated = false;
          }
          rrwl.readLock().lock();
        } finally {
          rrwl.writeLock().unlock(); 
        }   
    }   
    try {
         if (score % 2 == 0 ){
              health = "Bad Score";
          } else {
              health = "Good Score";
          }
    } finally {
          rrwl.readLock().unlock();
        }
    return health;
}
public void updateScore() {
    try {
        rrwl.writeLock().lock();
        //perform more task here
        scoreUpdated = true;
    }finally {
        rrwl.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
private int fetchScore() {
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    return calender.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
}
}
```

**ScoreUpdateThread**

```
public class ScoreUpdateThread implements Runnable {
private ScoreBoard scoreBoard;
public ScoreUpdateThread(ScoreBoard scoreTable) {
    this.scoreBoard = scoreTable;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i= 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Score Updated.");       
        scoreBoard.updateScore();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int threadCount = 2;
    final ExecutorService exService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    final ScoreBoard scoreBoard = new ScoreBoard();
    exService.execute(new ScoreUpdateThread(scoreBoard));
    exService.execute(new ScoreHealthThread(scoreBoard));           
    exService.shutdown();
}
}
```

Wont in the `ScoreBoard` while updating the `health` variable , we need to acquire the `WriteLock` since we are updating a shared variable ?

Comment: `ScoreBoard.updateScore()` *does* acquire the write lock before modifying anything: `rrwl.writeLock().lock()`. So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @John I am talking about the below code:                     
 if (score % 2 == 0 ){
              health = "Bad Score";
          } else {
              health = "Good Score";
          }    Here we are updating the health variable without acquiring any write lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wont in the `ScoreBoard` while updating the `health` variable , we need to acquire the `WriteLock` since we are updating a shared variable ?

You are correct that the class's `getMatchHealth()` method performs a modification of the shared `health` variable without holding the write lock.  There being no other mechanism in the class for synchronizinging those writes, this produces a data race when two threads invoke `getMatchHealth()` on the same `ScoreBoard` without engaging some form of external synchronization.  This appears to be a flaw in the method, and the method appears to have some other, more subtle synchronization issues, too.

Nevertheless, the program presented appears not ever to invoke `getMatchHealth()` at all, and the other `ScoreBoard` methods appear to be free of synchronization flaws, so the particular program presented is not affected by the flaws.  Still, unless those flaws are intentional -- for didactic purposes, for instance -- I would recommend finding a better source of tutorial material than the one that provided the example program.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly what issue you are facing, But the issue I think is:
1) You should make scoreUpdated and health variable to public and volatile, currently it is private and default respectively.

2)When you are taking write lock in method getMatchHealth() before releasing it you are again taking read lock, which you have released just before.

Comment: I have doubts regarding the existing code. I don't have the liberty to change the code. I want to know why in the below code are we updating health variable.            
  if (score % 2 == 0 ){
              health = "Bad Score";
          } else {
              health = "Good Score";
          }  without acquiring the write lock?